# Add numbering to apalike bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, numbering, apa-style

```
\documentclass {article}
\begin {document}

Cite this. \cite{paper}

\bibliography {bib}
\bibliographystyle {apalike}

\end {document}
```

I wish add numbering when generating my references

Comment: Your write-up isn't all that clear. Please explain what you mean by "add numbering". E.g., do you want to switch from having authoryear-type citation call-outs to numeric-style citation call-outs? Or should the numbers be in addition to the authoryear-based information? (If your objective concerns just the formatted bibliographic entries, e.g., prefixing entries with numbers: What are you trying to achieve by creating uninformative clutter?) Please advise.

Comment: @Mico When the bibliography is generated, I want them to prefix them with numbers , something like 

[1] Author and Author, Publication, 2003

Comment: @Mico Yes I want to prefix the entries with numbers. Not really because I want to create clutter, but rather because my institution template requires it to be so.